# Getting a list of all files with a certain date of last modified

Tags: c#, date, file-io, zip

I'm creating a program in c# that will get hold of all the files in a given directory that were
created on a specific date and then zip these files and store them in another directory. Sounds
plain and simple, I have a license for Teleriks components so that takes care of the zipping business.

BUT in order to select the files I use the following code:

```
        //Get all files created yesterday
        DateTime to_date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Path_Of_Files");

        var files = directory.GetFiles()
                    .Where(file => file.CreationTime <= to_date);

        if (files.Count() > 0)
        {
          //Zipping code here
        }
```

This however gives me ALL the files in the directory, so instead of zipping 700 files, it zips all 53'000 files in the folder, which isn't what I wanted.

When I look in the Windows Explorer I see the correct date in the "Last Modified" column, but for some reason my code refuse to acknowledge the same date. I've tried with both:

```
        var files = directory.GetFiles()
                    .Where(file => file.CreationTime <= to_date);
```

and

```
        var files = directory.GetFiles()
                    .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime <= to_date);
```

Both with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current `Where` expression will give you all files at *or before* this time yesterday. Perhaps you want something like:

```
var files = directory.GetFiles()
    .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime.Date == to_date.Date);
```

This checks that the *date* portion of the file's last modified date matches the *date* portion of the specified input date.